# Match matplotlib.pyplot.plot() with pd.plot() results (x-tick marks and legend)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used two graphing methods, and I am trying to replicate what I got from pd.plot() with matplotlib.pyplot.plot().

See the dataframe head below:
[image: dataframe head]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df_plot_graph.plot(figsize=(15,5))
```

[image: Plot1]
produces a different graph than

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.plot(df_plot_graph)
```

[image: Plot2]
How can I make the x-axis on the 2nd graph the same as the 1st graph?

Bonus would be how can I have the same legend that is showing up in the 1st graph (haven't researched this yet but would be helpful as well.)

Comment: Essentially you can't. While it's possible to make the pandas plot look like the matplotlib plot, you cannot do the inverse, because pandas uses different units and keeps its formatters pretty encapsulated and bound to the units it uses. You could of course write a custom formatter which does roughly the same as the pandas formatter. That is a bit of work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
    plt.xticks(range(min(valueX), max(valueX)+1))

Comment: the x value is a timestamp, so range() and +1 don't work with it